# How to I "edit as new" with Apple Mail?

Tags: mail.app, email

I have a mail message where I typed the email address from a business card. Unfortunately I made a typo, so it bounced. I'd like to open the mail and edit it as if it were a new mail without "Fwd" or "Re" and all that, but I can't find an option do to that with Apple Mail.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to sent messages.

[image]

Right click the message and click "Send again"

[image]

This will open the message as you wanted.

Comment: Indeed! I hadn't chosen that option, as I didn't want to send it again without edits (my fear of doing that drew me to the irrational conclusion that that is what "Send Again" would do!).

Comment: Nope, it just pulls up the editor again: doesn't send until you hit send :)

Comment: @drevicko Don't forget to mark it as solved!